# How to restart background php process? (how to get pid)

Tags: linux, shell, unix, pid, kill-process

I'm a PHP developer, and know very little about shell scripting... So I appreciate any help here.

I have four php scripts that I need running in the background on my server. I can launch them just fine - they work just fine - and I can kill them by looking up their PID.

The problem is I need my script to, from time to time, kill the processes and restart them, as they maintain long standing HTTP requests that sometimes are ended by the other side.

But I don't know how to write a command that'll find these processes and kill them without looking up the PID manually.

We'll start with one launch command :

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php -f /home/path/to/php_script.php > /dev/null &
```

Is there a way to "assign" a PID so it's always the same? or give the process a name? and how would I go about writing that new command?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you can't "assign" the process PID; instead, you should do as "real" daemons do: make your script save its own PID in some file, and then read it from that file when you need to kill.

Alternative would be to use something like [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), that handles all that for you in a quite nice way.

### Update - supervisor configuration

Since I mentioned supervisor, I'm also posting here a short supervisor configuration file that should do the job.

```
[program:yourscriptname]
command=/usr/local/php5/bin/php -f /home/path/to/php_script.php
```

[Have a look here for more configuration options](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#programx-section).

Then you can use it like this:

```
# supervisorctl status
```

to show the process(es) status.

```
# supervisorctl start yourscriptname
```

to start your script

```
# supervisorctl stop yourscriptname
```

to stop your script

### Update - real world supervisor configuration example

First of all, make sure you have this in your `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`.

```
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

if not, just add those two lines and

```
mkdir /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
```

Then, create a configurtion file for each process you want to launch:

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/script1.conf

```
[program:script1]
command=/usr/local/php5/bin/php -f /home/path/to/php_script.php
stdout_logfile=/var/log/script1.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/script1-error.log
```

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/script2.conf

```
[program:script2]
command=/usr/local/php5/bin/php -f /home/path/to/php_script2.php
stdout_logfile=/var/log/script2.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/script2-error.log
```

...etc, etc.. for all your scripts.

(note that you *don't* need the trailing & as supervisor will handle all the daemonization thing for you; in fact you *shouldn't* execute programs that are self-daemonizing inside supervisor).

Then you can start 'em all with:

```
supervisorctl start all
```

or just one with something like:

```
supervisorctl start script1
```

#### Starting supervisor from php

Of course, you can start/stop the supervisor-controlled processes using the two commands above, even from inside a script.

Remember however that you'll need root privileges, and it's quite risky to allow eg. a web page to execute commands as root on the server..

If that's the case, I recommend you have a look at the instructions on how to [run supervisor as a normal user](http://supervisord.org/running.html) (I never did that, but you should be able to run it as the www-data user too..).

Comment: yep, still can't figure it out... Let me make sure I've got this @redShadow.
I can create a .sh file that contains lines :
`[program:allmyphpscripts]`
`command=/usr/local/php5/bin/php -f /home/path/to/php_script.php  > /dev/null &`
`command=/usr/local/php5/bin/php -f /home/path/to/php_script2.php  > /dev/null &`
`command=/usr/local/php5/bin/php -f /home/path/to/php_script3.php  > /dev/null &` ect ect ect

then use `<?php exec('path/to/allmyphpscripts.sh'); ?>` to launch the supervisor.

and then I can use `<?php exec('supervisorctl stop allmyphpscripts'); ?>` to kill all my scripts? Thank you!

Comment: alright! thank you so much for taking the time to right it in layman's and so verbosely

Answer (score 3):

The canonical way to solve this is to have the process write its PID into a file in a known location, and then any utility scripts can look up the file, read the PID, and manipulate that process. Add a command line argument to the script that gives the name of the PID file to write to.

Comment: Beat me to it by 4s. So that's how you get 200k rep :)

Answer (score 0):

A work around to this would be to use `ps aux`, this will show all of the processes with the command that called them.  This presumes of course that the 4 scripts are different files, or can be uniquely identified by the command that called them.  Pipe that through a grep and you're all set `ps aux | grep runningscript.php`

Comment: this is quite hackerish and to be avoided, especially for "production" processes.. you're never 100% sure you'll match only the process you meant too.. and killing random processes is just bad.

Answer (score 0):

OK! so this has been a headache and a half for my who knows NOTHING about shell/bash whatever scripting...

@redShadow 's response would had been perfect, except my hosting provider will not give me access to the /etc/supervisor/ directory. as he said, you must be root - and even using `sudo` was an admin wouldn't let me make any chances there...

Here's what I came up with:

```
kill -9 `ps -ef | grep php | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
```

because the only types of commands I was executing showed up in the `top` command as `php` this command loops thru running processes, finds the `php` commands and their corresponding PIDs and KILLS them! woot!!

Comment: but i still have no idea what it means... and I'm afraid that @redShadow 's warning of randomly killing processes might come back to bite me in the ass down the road...

Answer (score 0):

What I do is have my script check for a file that I name "run.txt".  If it does not
exist, they exit. Then just br renaming that (empty) file, I can stop all my scripts.